# SQL Server Modulo function appears to return values outside of expected range

Tags: sql-server, modulo

While running a modulo function inside a case statement, there are many times that a value outside of the expected range is returned.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ABS(CheckSUM(NewId())) % 5 IN (0,1,2,3,4) then NULL 
       ELSE 'What Happened?' END
```

If you run this script a few times, you will see there are times that the result appears to be outside of the range of 0,1,2,3,4. My thinking is that this is somehow returning non-integer values during the case statement causing modulo to be an ineffective method of sorting by case.

Could someone explain what is happening in these cases so that I can combat this in the future?

NOTE: If I run the code modulo function by itself (outside of case statement) and return the results all values are in the range of 0,1,2,3,4 as expected.

Comment: How many times is many? I'm Just asking if this is duplicable 1/5 times or 1/5000 times?

Comment: @lrb I just tested on my SQL Server 2012 instance, every 3-7 times. Sometimes one after the other, seems random.

Comment: This one does it right all the time: `SELECT ABS(CheckSUM(NewId())),CASE WHEN ABS(CheckSUM(NewId())) %5>=0 AND ABS(CheckSUM(NewId()))%5<5 THEN NULL 
       ELSE 'What Happened?' END`

Comment: I ran it 100,000 times and it happend 32,914

Comment: @TT I believe each instance of NewId() in that query will produce a different value, though, right?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @TabAlleman I think so yes

Comment: There are LOTS of known SQL Server bugs relating to weird case expression.and subqueries and non-deterministic functions...

Comment: If you're using this in production you have grounds to file a bug report =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your statement to

```
SELECT top(1)
 CASE WHEN ABS(CheckSUM(NewId())) % 5 IN (0,1,2,3,4) then NULL 
       ELSE 'What Happened?' END
```

And have a look at the actual execution plan.

The `IN` part in the case is expanded to.

```
CASE WHEN abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)=(4) OR 
          abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)=(3) OR 
          abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)=(2) OR 
          abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)=(1) OR 
          abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)=(0) 
  THEN NULL 
  ELSE 'What Happened?' 
END
```

`abs(checksum(newid()))%(5)` is executed once for each value in the in clause.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?   I'm using 2012, and my execution plan doesn't show that.

Comment: @TabAlleman I see the same on SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and 2014. I have not tested on 2008R2. It is not visible in the estimated plan only in the actual plan.

Comment: Then why do I see something different?  I'm looking at the actual plan.   Do I need to do something differently?   I added a screenshot of my execution plan to my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman have a look at the XML version of the plan.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks. Easy fix to get around by separating into two steps. Was just an interesting observation that I wanted to find the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but I'm putting it here to format the code properly.

When I ran OP's code, I got a "What Happened?" the third time.   I wanted to see what Modulo WAS being returned when that happened, to see what insight it might provide, but to do that, I needed a non-moving NewID(), so I transposed his query to this:

```
DECLARE @NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

SELECT CASE WHEN ABS(CheckSUM(@NewID)) % 5 IN (0,1,2,3,4) then NULL 
       ELSE 'What Happened?' END
```

And I didn't get any occurrences of "What Happened?".

My best guess is that the SQL engine tries to get cute with the order of operations somehow and sometimes ends up doing the modulo on a non-numeric numerator.

But without being able to reproduce the behavior on a transposed query, it's impossible to "catch it in the act".

In the interest of making this an actual answer, I guess to combat this in the future, you should populate a variable with NEWID() rather than putting it inline in your query, if at all possible.

And other forms of "un-nesting" these operations might work as well.

Here is the execution plan I see when executing Mikael's query:

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: I was doing the same testing and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: I believe this is what is happening. In my specific situation, I can use a temp table to store the integer returned in the `ABS(CheckSUM(NewId())) % 5` statement and run a second process to run the case statement. Just seems like order of operations should allow for this to happen the way it is listed above.